# How to access second input element if page has two identical forms?

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

I am trying to automate form filling process using puppeteer. On one page, there are two forms which are very much the same, even their parent classes are the same.

I successfully filled the first form. But I don't know how to fill the second form, which has exactly the same input fields like username and all.

How can I differentiate between these two forms and access exactly the input fields I want.

For your reference, I am sharing some of my code down here.

```
await page.click('input[name="fullName"]');
await page.keyboard.type("Nitin");
```

Like above, I successfully filled the first form which has username field.
Now there is the second form which also has the same username field. Now how can I fill that one?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way would be to first get the element handles of both forms via [`page.$$`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/v1.14.0/docs/api.md#pageselector-1) and then use another query to query its child elements.

**Example**

```js
const forms = await page.$$('form'); // array contains the form element handles

const elementInForm1 = await forms[0].$('input[name="fullName"]');
await elementInForm1.click();
// ...

const elementInForm2 = await forms[1].$('input[name="fullName"]');
await elementInForm2.click();
// ...
```

The variable `forms` contains all `form` elements inside the page. By using [`elementHandle.$`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/v1.14.0/docs/api.md#elementhandleselector) you can then query an element inside another element.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`page.$$()`](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pageevaluatepagefunction-args) or [`page.evaluate(`)](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pageevaluatepagefunction-args) to cycle through forms before searching for elements.